# How to load Controller to SpringMVC at runtime

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm having a problem about how to load controller to SpringMVC at runtime. My project is using SpringMVC framework and combines with Dynamic Module OSGi model. Currently, I used Gemini Blueprint to implement OSGi and separated to 2 bundle.
Let's assuming, two bundle are:

 - Bundle A: a web application use Spring MVC. It's deployed first

 - Bundle B: a bundle only contains classes @Controller. It represents the features that will be upgraded later.

 A problem at this time that how to classes's Controller in bundle B can load to bundle A at runtime. So i search how to programmatically add controller and find out a solution. See [HERE](http://davidwelch.co/java-stack/programmatically-add-controllers-to-spring-mvc). After that, at bundle A, I register that object to OSGi Container to bundle B can reference and invokes a register controller method.
The following code like this. First, at the bundle A:

```
  @Component
    public class RegistryController implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor {
        private BeanDefinitionRegistry registry;
    
        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
    
        }
    
        @Override
        public void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
            this.registry = registry;
        }
    
        public void registryController(Class<?> clazz, String beanName) {
            BeanDefinition bean = new RootBeanDefinition(clazz);
            registry.registerBeanDefinition(beanName, bean);
        }
    }

    <osgi:service interface="com.test.bundleA.config.RegistryController " ref="RegistryController" />
```

And then, at the bundle B, I will reference RegistryController object from bundle A and call to registryController() method.

```
<osgi:reference id="registryController"
        interface="com.test.bundleA.config.RegistryController">
        <osgi:reference-listener ref="registryControllerListener"
            bind-method="bind" />
</osgi:reference>

@Component
public class RegistryControllerListener {
    public void bind(RegistryController registry) {
        System.out.println("Binding: " + registry);
        registry.registryController(TestController.class, "testController");
    }
}

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping
    public String test() {
        return "TEST";
    }
}
```

After done, I start deploying bundles to OSGi Container: bundle A first, then bundle B. As per my observation, TestController bean is registered to bundle A, but when I test in browser with url "/test", "Not page found" message is shown. I try refresh Web Application Context but the result still don't change. Refresh Web Application Context only reload beans that are defined in file .xml.
I hope somebody will help me. Thanks for reading